# How to make Emacs reload the TAGS file automatically?

Tags: emacs

When the TAGS file is re-generated, and I try to visit tag in Emacs (<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>), Emacs asks me if I really want to re-read that file:

> Tags file /path/to/TAGS has changed, read new contents? (yes or no)

And I have to enter `yes` every time. Not very convenient (<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> are 7 keys to press against only 2 in Vim).

How can I configure Emacs to read the updated TAGS silently, without asking?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
(setq tags-revert-without-query 1)
```

**Edit**: before finding the above answer, I suggested adding this line:

```
(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)
```

to `.emacs` file, because every time you're asked if you want to reread that file, you'll just have to hit 'y' if you prefer not to use `tags-revert-without-query`. In that case, <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> is just one keystroke more than Vim.

I'll leave that information here in case somebody finds it useful.

Comment: Thank you. Some questions which require yes-or-no are serious. I'd prefer not to enable <kbd>y</kbd> for all of them.

Comment: @jetxee: Yes, you're right. Sometimes it can be dangerous. Forces you to read before you hit a key :-) I've updated my answer with one possible solution to your problem. Is that what you needed?

Comment: Can't vote for the answer with that `defalias` call, the edit (IMO) should have removed everything above the **Edit:** line.

Comment: @Trey: edited. I didn't want to remove everything because other comments wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you. `tags-revert-without-query` is what I need.

Comment: Thank you for this. Before I found this I was going crazy. I kept not noticing the prompt, going on to do something else, only to get hit with an unexpected "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer" error later. For example, I would not notice that Emacs had displayed the prompt, then try to open a file while it was displayed.

Comment: Customizing Emacs to more or less usable state takes more time than editing actual files with it.